# How to judge a linear transformation A(n dimension) satisfies $A^k=0$ and finds the number of Jordan blocks normally(not depend on specific numbers)

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, number-theory

We know that if a linear transformation $\mathbb{A}$in a n-dimensional space $V$ satisfies:$$\mathbb{A}^{n-1}\neq 0,\quad \mathbb{A}^n=0$$we could find a vector $\epsilon$ s.t.$$\mathbb{A}\epsilon\neq 0$$then $$\epsilon,\mathbb{A}\epsilon,\mathbb{A}^2\epsilon,\dotso,\mathbb{A}^{n-1}\epsilon$$could be a basis of the space $V$, i.e. the basis could be displayed by a vector $\epsilon$.

While in the number theory, we are solving the problem of$$x^n\equiv 1\mod 
 p$$and $p$ is a prime number, we have already know when $p$ has a primitive root iff $p$ is the form of $k^\alpha,\,2k^\alpha\,,2\,,4$, in which k is an odd prime number. We set the primitive number a $u$, then $\forall i\in \mathbb{N},0\leq i\leq p-1$, there exists a positive integer $l$ s.t.$$u^l\equiv i\mod p$$i.e. each element in mod $p$ can be demonstrated by $u$.

What I'm thinking about is whether we could put the theory in the matrix calulating progress above, as the caculation of $\mathbb{A}$ only take place at integers, and they have similar properties.

When it comes to a more natural situation, we can know from Euler theorem that $a^{\phi(p)}\equiv 1(mod p)$. This is suitable for all $p$s. Could we find some properties of $\mathbb{A},\, s.t. \,\mathbb{A}^k=0(k\leq n)$

Another question is that in the progress of the normalization of matrix(changing the matrix into Jordan matrix), how can we find the number of Jordan blocks belonging to the same eigenvalue $\lambda_0$ and the one with highest dimension(so that we can find the minimal polynomial). I know how to calculate a specific situation(given what $\mathbb{A}$ is in number). But is there any more normal conclusions or classifications of $\epsilon$. Maybe in the group theory, it can explained clearly(I don't know).

I think we can restrict the space $V$ as the $\mathbb{R}^n$

Any helpful thoughts about this is ok!

Comment: I think the requirement is that $A^{n-1}\epsilon \neq 0$, as opposed to $A\epsilon \neq 0$. Consider for example $\displaystyle A = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ and $\epsilon = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$. Then $A\epsilon \neq 0$, but $A^2 \epsilon = 0$, so $\{\epsilon, A\epsilon, A^2\epsilon\}$ is not a basis.

Comment: Thx! what you say is exactly I want to express. But the question is not the one I wanna ask. plz wait for me to adjust it

Comment: I am not really saure what you are asking, but it seems strange that you want to restrict to $V = {\mathbb R}^n$. If you are trying to calculate Jordan blocks, then a more natural choice is ${\mathbb C}^n$, because ${\mathbb C}$ is algebraically closed and will contain all of the eigenvalues.